# Cantor pairing function vs. Morton encoding?

Tags: encoding, pairing

why don't the Cantor Pairing function references discuss the Morton code, or Z-order space filling curves?

they seem to generate similar results with a single larger number uniquely represents number pairs or triples.

- [Cantor pairing function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function)
- [Morton code, or Z-order curves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve)
- there are others, for example the [Rosenberg-Strong pairing function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.04129.pdf)

both have encoding and decoding methods.

when to use which method???

the [pymorton library](https://github.com/trevorprater/pymorton) seems mature and handles floating point numbers especially for the relevant bits of (lat,lon,elev) geographic points

Comment: The Cantor pairing function isn't a space-filling curve at all. It is a way of reading off a table via short diagonals. If there is a nice library for Z-order curves, that might be a good pragmatic reason to use those.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. both generate unique mappings, and the inverse, from multiple numbers to a single number. in this respect they're quite similar

Comment: It does answer the question in the first sentence. The topics didn't seem sufficiently close to the writers of that Wikipedia article to link them. Discrete space-filling curves are designed to have good locality (nearby points in space tend to map to nearby points on the line). That isn't a consideration with Cantor's pairing function. On the other hand, I concede that there is some similarity.